# Junit Test of private mthods

Tags: java, reflection, junit

I am attempting to write a utility method to allow easy invocation of private methods in classes under test.
What I have is this:

```
private Object callPrivateMethod(String methodName, Object subject, Object... parameters) {

    try {
        Class<?>[] paramTypes = new Class<?>[parameters.length];
        for (int index=0; index<parameters.length; index++) {
            paramTypes[index] = parameters[index].getClass();
        }
        Method method = subject.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName, paramTypes);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        return method.invoke(subject, parameters);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        fail(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

But when I attempt to call it using this code:

```
List<Session> sessions = new ArrayList<Session>();
// fill the array list
String sessionLines = (String) callPrivateMethod("getSessionsForEmail", emailSender, sessions);
```

I get this exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: staffing.server.email.EmailSender.getSessionsForEmail(java.util.ArrayList)
```

The method signature in EmailSender (class under test) look like this:

```
private String getSessionsForEmail(List<Session> sessions) {
   //do stuff
}
```

Trying to figure out why reflection can't find the method. It is something to to with List and ArrayList not being exactly the same class? If so, what can I do?

Comment: on the `getDeclaredMethod` line or on the `invoke` line?

Comment: on the getDeclaredMethod line

Comment: I guess because it looks for a `getSessionsForEmail(ArrayList<Session> sessions)` method. You need to work backwards I think...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code tries to find a method taking an `ArrayList` (the concrete class of `sessions`) as argument. But your method doesn't take an `ArrayList` as argument. It takes a `List` as argument.

You'll need to pass the types of the parameters of the method in addition to the values of the parameters.

Or you could refactor the code and either make the method protected or package-protected, or put it in another collaborating class as a public method.

Comment: modified callPrivateMethod to take list of parameter types, now works. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It is best practice to not directly test private methods.  By accessing them through the public and/or protected methods, we are testing how the system would behave in production.  This approach will also allow you to manage test coverage through sending all combinations of data through the public/protected methods.

Protected methods can be tested by having the same package name in the test source folder.

If testing private methods is a must, then instead of doing the reflection yourself, you might go with a mocking tool such as Powermock, preferably with Mockito.  Both these tools have a good integration with JUnit.  It is a steep learning curve, but well worth the investment.  Here is more detail: [Testing Private method using mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799439/testing-private-method-using-mockito)

Comment: I disagree - there's nothing inherently wrong with testing private methods if you wish.  Better to do that than to expose them in the public interface simply for the sake of testing or not testing at all.

Comment: Yes, I see your point and in some cases it may be a must.  Usually, there will be a public/protected method that provides the functionality of the class to external classes.

Comment: But if I make the private I don't want them to be exposed.  And I want to test them.  Still say the OP's idea is a bad one?  I don't.  "Never test private" is too knee-jerk and dogmatic for me.

Comment: I think it is just style/architecture and not necessarily a bad idea.  There rarely are any private methods that will not be eventually called from a publicly accessible method.  Even in the case of singletons and private methods being called from a private constructor, the `getInstance` or similar method still starts the chain.  I agree there are cases  where you would need to do it.

Comment: Looks like the wisdom of testing private methods in a matter of opinion. My opinion is that it should be done - the whole idea of unit tests is to check small parts in isolation, to check methods really do what is intended. That includes private method. Production code should not have unit-test specific methods etc, but should be designed to be unit-testable.

Answer (score 0):

Current reasoning says you shouldn't test private methods. Either they are implementation specific and should be tested through the methods that call them. Or they should be extracted into their own class and tested via that. The thinking is if you have private methods that do so much they need testing individually, your class does too much and should be broken up.

There are a number of advantages of looking at it this way, not the least escaping having to hack your class to test it.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to be successful with your own implementation, I feel like it might be useful to look at : [Type erasure in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Otherwise, as Akber Choudhry pointed there is a nice utility package coming with Mockito, called org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox. I would definitely use it.

Finally, I would not say never ever test private methods but if you intend to test them please think twice. Maintaining reflection based approach is not the easiest thing and quite error prone.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with **JUnit4 + Mockito**.

To mock private methods we could simply use mockit.Deencapsulation package:

```
Deencapsulation.invoke(myService, "methodName", arg1, arg2);
```

We can replace arguments with Mockito.anyString() etc as per requirements.