# Specify return value for private method mockito

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I have a situation like this

```
class A{


    public method1(){

     result = method2();
    }

    private method2(){
      result = method3()
      some processing;
      return result2;
    }
    private method3(){
      processing;
      return result;

    }
  }
```

I want to test `method1()`, but when `method2` calls `method3`, I don't want actual `method3` to execute, but return value I want. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Wouldn't executing method3 be necessary in order to return the result?

Comment: @DizzyCode For unit tests I want to provide my own results from method3, instead of one returned from executing it. So something like when(method3()).then(my result)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799439/testing-private-method-using-mockito

Comment: If you really want your method3 not to be executed, there is a design issue in your class. The method3 should be in another class B, and there would be a dependency of class B in class A which you could stub in your test.
Then you would have something like this : when(b.method3()).thenReturn(xxx)

Comment: @DamienBeaufils I realized that, and I put it into a different class. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The simplest solution is to comment out the line: result = method3() in your implementation of method 2, and instead set result to be equal to the return value that you want from method3.