# Can't find a private method exception, while testing a private method

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to write the unit test case for my private method in scala using MockitoSugar but it is throwing Can't find a private method exception. Here is my code.

```
      object ActivityRepo{

        private def addActivity(activity:Activity):Future[Activity]={
              //doing DB calls
          }
      }
```

Unit test:

```
      "Activity Repo Test" must {

        "add Activity" in {
          // doing mock for the DB calls

          val addActivity = PrivateMethod[Future[Activity]]('addActivity)

          val result = ActivityRepo invokePrivate addActivity (activity)
          // doing assertions      
         }
      }
```

Where is the mistake?

Comment: I think it can be fixed by adding package access to method: `private[package-name] addActivity`

Comment: Maybe you should read this.
[Testing Private method using mockito](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799439/testing-private-method-using-mockito)

Comment: Make sure that the type of `activity` is Activity