# Mock private void method with parameters using Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am trying to mock a private void method with parameters using Mockito  as below:

```
MyClass clsSpy = spy(new MyClass());
doNothing().when(clsSpy, method("privateMethod", String.class, boolean.class))
    .withArguments(any(String.class), any(boolean.class));
```

but it is not able to find the symbol `method`.

I know this can be done with the help of PowerMock. But is there a way to do this using Mockito only?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question already has an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799439/testing-private-method-using-mockito

Comment: As properly explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8799482/1997376) no you can't mock a `private` method with `Mockito` because it should never happen unless you have a design issue in your code, it is only doable with `PowerMock`.