# How to write test case for private void m1(Dto dto){ } by using PowerMockito

Tags: java, mockito, private, void, powermockito

Please help me how can I write test case for private void method which takes pojo class as an argument and set some class methods in side. I mean inside  that method some setmethods are calling.
This private method is called in constructor but i want to test or write test case for that private method.

Ex:

```
private void M1(Dto obj1) {
   anotherclass.setSometMethod(someClass.getId());
}
```

Please let me know how we can do it using PowerMockito. I don't want to use Reflection.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Testing Private method using mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799439/testing-private-method-using-mockito)

Comment: Hi Jonk, could you give  an example, I tried that example which you have  mentioned  link but not working  below is example which i need to test.   private void initializeFields(final DeviceGroupDTO deviceGroupDTO) {
  if (deviceGroupDTO != null) {
   this.deviceGroupName.setValue(deviceGroupDTO.getName());
   if (deviceGroupDTO.getCustomer() != null) {
    this.customerSelector.setSelected(deviceGroupDTO.getCustomer().getId());
   }
  }

Comment: Please add code by editing your question instead. You should also add the testcase you have tried to write and any exception/error you now have.