# How to mock a response of a particular method in java?

Tags: java, mockito

I have a class like this

```
public class Foo {

 public String getData(String id) {
    JsonObject json = this.somePrivateMethod(id);
    String d = // some manipulation
    return d;
 }
 private JsonObject somePrivateMethod(String id) {
 
   
 }
}
```

I am trying to write the unit test for `getData`
Now, I want to mock this `somePrivateMethod` with two jsons

```
goodJson = {1: 2}, badJson = {"foo" : "bar"}
```

How do I mock that private method in java.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Testing Private method using mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799439/testing-private-method-using-mockito)

Comment: Powermock: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803944/how-to-mock-private-method-for-testing-using-powermock

Comment: If you're testing `getData`, then you shouldn't stub `somePrivateMethod`.  The behaviour of `somePrivateMethod` is part of the contract of `getData`, and therefore, there should be a valid test of `getData` that would only pass if `somePrivateMethod` were not stubbed.  As a general rule, if the answer is "PowerMock", then you've asked the wrong question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use frameworks like Mockito to achieve the mocking.

```
when(good.getData()).then(json)
```

So when your test case runs and when it encounters getData() method then it responses the json object from the then() method

Comment: gotcha.. does it work with private methods?

Comment: @frazman See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8799439/1707353).

Comment: For testing private methods you can use PowerMock